# How to upload image to server in high quality and fast

Tags: android, image, memory-management, android-bitmap

Actually I'm trying to upload image into server with excellent quality .Currently I'm converting an array of bitmap to `base64` string `arrayList` and then sending that to server by `socket.io`.But the problem is when I'm trying to increase the quality of bitmap the `base64` conversion is taking a lot of time and it's quite inefficient .Even after taking so much time I'm getting low quality images in server .So can anyone please help me to fix this problem and increase the efficiency of upload ?

Code:

```
public ArrayList<String> convert(ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmap){
    ArrayList<String> pics=new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i=0;i<bitmap.size();i++){
        pics.add(getStringImage(bitmap.get(i)));
    }
    return pics;
}
public static String getStringImage(Bitmap bmp){
    //I've givent maxSize as 500
    int outWidth;
    int outHeight;
    int inWidth = bmp.getWidth();
    int inHeight = bmp.getHeight();
    if(inWidth > inHeight){
        outWidth = maxSize;
        outHeight = (inHeight * maxSize) / inWidth;
    } else {
        outHeight = maxSize;
        outWidth = (inWidth * maxSize) / inHeight;
    }

    Bitmap new_bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, outWidth, outHeight, false);
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    new_bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
    byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
    String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
    return encodedImage;
}

// Sending to server
final JSONObject obji=new JSONObject();
                    try {
                        //bit is arraylist of bitmap
                        obji.put("uploads_username",username);
                        obji.put("uploads",convert(bit));
                        socket.emit("data",obji);
                        }catch(Exception e){
                                }
```

Comment: The bigger the image the longer it is going to take to convert/upload. Converting an image to a base64 string is also not the most efficient way about uploading images either

Comment: is your bottleneck at the conversion or uploading ?

Comment: @tyczj could you please tell what's more efficient than base64 string

Comment: you can check this tutorial https://www.androidhive.info/2014/12/android-uploading-camera-image-video-to-server-with-progress-bar/

Comment: @AngelKoh in conversion no problem is there in uploading

Comment: A better way would be a stream upload where you upload the file itself. Base64 increases the size of the data transferred by about 33%, `multipart/form-data` is the standard way of transferring binary data